# How to get href attributr value in vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I´m new to vue.js and I have a query.

How can we get the `href` attribute value of a HTML variable.

```
<pre>
    var custompath = '<a href="undefined111">a8AZCtgt</a>'
</pre>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can make a scratch div, set its `innerHTML` to your HTML, and then get either the `href` property (which will be the full computed URL) or the attribute (just the string as you assigned it) from the first child node.

```js
var custompath = '<a href="undefined111">a8AZCtgt</a>';
const scratchDiv = document.createElement('div');
scratchDiv.innerHTML = custompath;
const a = scratchDiv.childNodes[0];
console.log('Href prop:', a.href);
console.log('Href attr:', a.getAttribute('href'));
```